# Ignored silent flag in a test run

Tags: unit-testing, prolog, swi-prolog, plunit

I'm currently trying to use the [PlUnit](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%280,%270%27,swi%28%27/doc/packages/plunit.html%27%29%29) test suit and encounter a problem to turn off the output of my predicates during the test.

The [documentation](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%282,%276%27,swi%28%27/doc/packages/plunit.html%27%29%29) says that I should be fine with something along the lines of `set_test_options([silent(true)]).`, however that doesn't seem to have any effect on my test runs.

I tried to put those options into my `load_test_files/1` call as well, but it didn't change anything.

If anyone can provide help about this library that'll be gratefully read, as I seem to misunderstand the documentation and am getting nowhere when trying to see what fails here.

Comment: plunit is still in some motion, so the SWI list is definitely a better place for your question.

Comment: ok, I've forwarded the question. Thanks :)